# Angular: Accessing a promise from a controller within a service

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-promise

I'm using an API in my app that has a few steps:

1. Load full data from API 1
2. Get some of that data and use that to make params for the next API call
3. One that API call has been made, make a nvd3 chart (via a directive)

Controller:

```
$scope.deferred = $q.defer()

function makeChart(start, finish) {    
  api.getDetail(start, fin).then(function(throughput) {
    $scope.chartData = throughput;
    $scope.deferred.resolve();
  }, function(err) {
     console.log(err);
  })
}

api.getDetail(id).then(function(job){
  makeChart(job.start, job.finish);
})
```

// Directive

```
.directive('niceChart', [function(){
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        replace: true,
        template: '<div>Nice Template!</div>',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
        scope.deferred.then(function(){

         // Do stuff 

        })
      }
    }

 }])
```

When I do this I get `scope.deferred.then is not a function`.

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this code:

```
scope.deferred.promise.then(function(){
  // Do stuff 
})
```

The `deferred` object itself is not a promise, so it doesn't have the necessary methods. You should access the promise object: scope.deferred.promise.

But I recommend you to refactor the code to the following, sending the `promise` object as parameter:

```
var deferred = $q.defer()
$scope.promise = deferred.promise;

function makeChart(start, finish) {    
  api.getDetail(start, fin).then(function(throughput) {
    $scope.chartData = throughput;
    deferred.resolve();
  }, function(err) {
     console.log(err);
  })
}

api.getDetail(id).then(function(job){
  makeChart(job.start, job.finish);
})

////////////////////////////

.directive('niceChart', [function(){
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        replace: true,
        template: '<div>Nice Template!</div>',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
        scope.promise.then(function(){

         // Do stuff 

        })
      }
    }

 }])
```

Comment: Oh? I'm a little confused. Looking at the first example here: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q, does this mean that running `$q.defer()` adds a `.then()` property to whatever function it's inside?

Comment: `$q.defer()` returns a deferred object which has `.resolve()`, `.reject()` and `.promise`. The `deferred.promise` has `.then()`, `.catch()` and `finally()`

Comment: Ahhh ok, I didn't see the `return deferred.promise` in the link above and it messed me up. Thanks mate!

Comment: @Jascination Glad to help.